# next without for error excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, iteration

I don't understand why this code has compile error Next without For
Please help :(

```
Sub DefColorCodes()

    For i = 2 To 5
        Range("actReg").Value = Range("Sheet1!A" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("actReg").Select
        With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Range(Range("actRegCode").Value).Interior.Color

    Next i

    Range("B17").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You need an **End With** before the **Next**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't ending your `With`. Add an `End With` line at some point before your `Next i` line.

```
Sub DefColorCodes()
    For i = 2 To 5
        Range("actReg").Value = Range("Sheet1!A" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("actReg").Select
        With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Range(Range("actRegCode").Value).Interior.Color
        End With
    Next i
    Range("B17").Select
End Sub
```

In this case it's quite possible that you didn't mean to use a `With` at all:

```
Sub DefColorCodes()
    For i = 2 To 5
        Range("actReg").Value = Range("Sheet1!A" & i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("actReg").Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Range(Range("actRegCode").Value).Interior.Color
    Next i
    Range("B17").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: @MiloKang: Great! If you could accept my answer this will let users know that the solution worked for you. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `With` statement inside your for loop with out a `End With`